# Поток с независимой скоростью выполения от программы

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi

Создаю поток CreateThread и через него обновляю содержимое элемента в программе. Но скорость обновление очень мала, 1 раз в 15 секунд. Как сделать поток не зависимым от программы?
По просьбам желающих подробней все опишу:
Если создать поток он будет выводить сообщение с большой скоростью таким образом:

```
char *dwThrdParam = "Hello!";
    DWORD dwThreadId;
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, UpdateList, dwThrdParam, 0, &dwThreadId);
    .......
DWORD WINAPI UpdateList(LPVOID lParam)
{
int c = 0;
for (;;)
{
        UpdateProcessList(listView, Process);

        char b[20];
        sprintf_s(b, "%s, %d\n",(char*)lParam, c);
        OutputDebugString(b);
        c++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Но когда в цикле не потока!!! А программы я начинаю писать код, который уменьшает количество проходов цикла с нескольких тысяч до 30 раз в секунду, то поток начинает выводить сообщение раз в 15 секунд. Вот код цикла программы:

```
VSync.Begin(30);
        while (globalRunning)
        {
            if (PeekMessage(&message, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&message);
                DispatchMessage(&message);
            }

            VSync.End(false);
        }
```

VSync основан на sleep. Интересная особенность если начать перемещать окно за заголовок, то скорость потока увеличивается во много раз
Для тех кто уверен что в расчете дело:

```
char buffer[256];
LVITEM lvi;
memset(&lvi, 0, sizeof(lvi));
lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_TEXT;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{   
        lvi.iItem = i;

        lvi.iSubItem = 0;
        ListView_InsertItem(listView, &lvi);
        sprintf_s(buffer, "%d", i);
        ListView_SetItemText(listView, currentItem, lvi.iSubItem, buffer);
}
```

Comment: Что вы понимаете под независимостью от программы?

Comment: ну может быть сам расчет содержимого для элемента занимает 15 секунд?

Comment: Нужно больше подробностей. Потоки работают асинхронно относительно самой программы, если вы сами синхронизацию не делали.

Comment: Под независимостью я подразумеваю, что скорость потока не должна сильно меняться от кода написанного в программе и не относящегося к потоку

Comment: Расчет содержимого занимает долю милисекунд

Comment: Синхронизацию не делал, просто создал поток и зациклил его

Comment: в коде выше нет места "рассчета". PeekMessage - он может блокировать тред до получения сообщений. Если перемещать окно - генерируются события, PeekMessage работает "быстро". Дальше надеюсь понятно.

Comment: Добавил расчет. Значит PeekMessage  блокирует поток и позволяет ему проходить цикл за 15 секунд???  Я не понимаю причем тут PeekMessage работает быстро

Comment: Внутри цикла Вы пытаетесь вставить элементы внутрь списка. А не думали о том, что это также использует сообщения. И как следствие, похоже, что Вы сами себя блокируете.

Comment: Кстати возможно да, я просто не знаю как устроены ListView функции.
А не подскажите, как решить эту проблему? Сейчас на MSDN зашел
You can use this macro or send the LVM_INSERTITEM message explicitly. написано, похоже сообщения используют